# youtube-dl returning <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

Tags: python, linux, google-compute-engine, youtube-dl

I have a google compute engine server that I'm trying to run youtube-dl. The server is in US Iowa, it is running debian 9.11

This is the returned debug output:

```
youtube-dl -v https://youtu.be/tAfedFkfIiU

[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'-v', u'https://youtu.be/tAfedFkfIiU']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs UTF-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2019.11.22
[debug] Python version 2.7.13 (CPython) - Linux-4.9.0-11-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.11
[debug] exe versions: none
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[youtube] tAfedFkfIiU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] tAfedFkfIiU: Downloading video info webpage
[debug] Default format spec: best/bestvideo+bestaudio
[debug] Invoking downloader on u'https://r6---sn-5uaeznkz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1574879492&ei=pGzeXZCILYKGigTm34n4DQ&ip=35.209.8.202&id=o-AGcuKL5f7Y7Du-FaWbBZhMaLIsfRZox4FQAYtAj_ujri&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-5uaeznkz%2Csn-tt1eln7e&ms=au%2Conr&mv=u&mvi=5&pl=16&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=1008.047&lmt=1574810711552172&mt=1574857344&fvip=6&fexp=23842630&beids=9466585&c=WEB&txp=5535432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgF6wvUZ9ogFyTSHe6BQib6D9Ib4x8Q4_FDuMP70zbnkgCID5CAhySBvgNYaeH9kwkP-vkecmrngFh7b8NYtnIs8RN&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAMn1kcyvqttNBRifOFDTcOYcyGbSttZb4lyxiOq2j0JcAiAwnqjvkIAnBIDPOdjIxlDkZvVHhgqL_kLPj_NQEMyvoA%3D%3D'
ERROR: unable to download video data: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1925, in process_info
    success = dl(filename, info_dict)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1864, in dl
    return fd.download(name, info)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py", line 366, in download
    return self.real_download(filename, info_dict)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/downloader/http.py", line 341, in real_download
    establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/downloader/http.py", line 109, in establish_connection
    ctx.data = self.ydl.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2237, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2724, in https_open
    req, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Things I've tried:

- Allowed all network traffic through the google cloud firewall, both ingress and egress for all protocol types:
  [image: firewall rules]
- Uninstalled curl and youtube-dl and reinstalled youtube-dl using wget
- Pinging youtube.com and google.com returns a good response.
- I can access my private web page from the server, so the ports are definitely working and theres definitely network access to everything outside the server.
- No network issues arose other than this.
- The direct link in the verbose output yields an "Access Denied" error, yet when trying youtube-dl locally, it returns a link that I can access and my friend with another IP can access, so it seems youtube-dl is returning non-accessible links? Unsure. [image: access denied]
- I have not sent too many requests to get blacklisted, It didn't work from the start.
- The IP is ephemeral, it changes every time the server boots up (no static external IP set).
- Deleting and remaking the server instance from scratch does not fix the issue.
- The author of the library is adamant that it is a network issue on my side and not their side as seen in this github issue here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/23213
- I thought it might be that `urllib2.urlopen` is unaccessible in gcloud, but I ran a small python script that runs the method and it pinged google.com properly.
- I cannot `wget` the direct link provided in the verbose log output. It times out. This is the output log of wget with -v and curl with -v:

wget:

```
wget "https://r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1575026099&ei=U6ngXd3cDImjtQfFkKHACA&ip=35.209.8.202&id=o-ALJhUmz-vDQxpGilTFwb8v02UpFXo3JFaLZVvTV7BcGV&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5ualdn7y%2Csn-5uaeznrz&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=u&mvi=5&pl=16&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=634.090&lmt=1574939877997808&mt=1575004312&fvip=2&fexp=23842630&beids=9466587&c=WEB&txp=6531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgWkUIL8i20_R0aDMs-UQmZq-EbHExzRFoP2ql6wqq3hoCIHKcxV7eU5sfcYxLzzVgJ1LgSoebvlUXnObwqDmzy7ym&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhANYw5qlL2ITIfsqPs5fveDiJljYvLCb8m4HLtoZDzTWmAiEA59uqA-cPmDAIgKRTYMXbxoegXat81xaZppigC76m7pQ%3D" -v
The name is too long, 708 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is videoplayback?expire=1575026099&ei=U6ngXd3cDImjtQfFkKHACA&ip=35.209.8.202&id=o-ALJhUmz-vDQxpGilTFwb8v02UpFXo3JFaLZVvTV7BcGV&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5ualdn7y%2Csn-5uaeznrz&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=u&mvi=5&pl=16&mime=.
--2019-11-29 05:15:14--  https://r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1575026099&ei=U6ngXd3cDImjtQfFkKHACA&ip=35.209.8.202&id=o-ALJhUmz-vDQxpGilTFwb8v02UpFXo3JFaLZVvTV7BcGV&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-5ualdn7y%2Csn-5uaeznrz&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=u&mvi=5&pl=16&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=634.090&lmt=1574939877997808&mt=1575004312&fvip=2&fexp=23842630&beids=9466587&c=WEB&txp=6531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgWkUIL8i20_R0aDMs-UQmZq-EbHExzRFoP2ql6wqq3hoCIHKcxV7eU5sfcYxLzzVgJ1LgSoebvlUXnObwqDmzy7ym&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl&lsig=AHylml4wRgIhANYw5qlL2ITIfsqPs5fveDiJljYvLCb8m4HLtoZDzTWmAiEA59uqA-cPmDAIgKRTYMXbxoegXat81xaZppigC76m7pQ%3D
Resolving r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com (r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com)... 173.194.147.204, 2607:f8b0:4002:35::c
Connecting to r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com (r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com)|173.194.147.204|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com (r6---sn-5ualdn7y.googlevideo.com)|2607:f8b0:4002:35::c|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

curl:

```
curl -O -v https://r2---sn-hgn7rn7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1575026099&ei=U6ngXd3cDImjtQfFkKHACA&ip=35.209.8.202&id=o-ALJhUmz-vDQxpGilTFwb8v02UpFXo3JFaLZVvTV7BcGV&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mime=video/mp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=634.090&lmt=1574939877997808&fvip=2&fexp=9466587,23842630&beids=9466587&c=WEB&txp=6531432&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,mime,ratebypass,dur,lmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgWkUIL8i20_R0aDMs-UQmZq-EbHExzRFoP2ql6wqq3hoCIHKcxV7eU5sfcYxLzzVgJ1LgSoebvlUXnObwqDmzy7ym&rm=sn-5uakd7d&req_id=db99eec2ba1fa3ee&ipbypass=yes&redirect_counter=2&cm2rm=sn-uxgg5oxu-cxte7l&cms_redirect=yes&mip=213.204.90.117&mm=29&mn=sn-hgn7rn7r&ms=rdu&mt=1575004548&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=24&lsparams=ipbypass,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AHylml4wRQIgK50gSfkEix6Q7q9n2GTk7GQOn6YEZ1NqiX4l8UwDHhQCIQDT4Q4KoFB6Dck1vQj0FO27LvNA8PMVyNJOaFMcU9yutg==
[1] 3670
[2] 3671
[3] 3672
[4] 3673
[5] 3674
[6] 3675
[7] 3676
[8] 3677
[9] 3678
[10] 3679
[11] 3680
[12] 3681
[13] 3682
[14] 3683
[15] 3684
[16] 3685
[17] 3686
[18] 3687
[19] 3688
[20] 3689
[21] 3690
[22] 3691
[23] 3692
[24] 3693
[25] 3694
[26] 3695
[27] 3696
[28] 3697
[29] 3698
[30] 3699
[31] 3700
[32] 3701
[33] 3702
[2]   Done                    ei=U6ngXd3cDImjtQfFkKHACA
[3]   Done                    ip=35.209.8.202
[4]   Done                    id=o-ALJhUmz-vDQxpGilTFwb8v02UpFXo3JFaLZVvTV7BcGV
[5]   Done                    itag=22
[6]   Done                    source=youtube
[7]   Done                    requiressl=yes
[8]   Done                    mime=video/mp4
[9]   Done                    ratebypass=yes
[10]   Done                    dur=634.090
[11]   Done                    lmt=1574939877997808
[12]   Done                    fvip=2
[13]   Done                    fexp=9466587,23842630
[14]   Done                    beids=9466587
[15]   Done                    c=WEB
[16]   Done                    txp=6531432
[17]   Done                    sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,mime,ratebypass,dur,lmt
[18]   Done                    sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgWkUIL8i20_R0aDMs-UQmZq-EbHExzRFoP2ql6wqq3hoCIHKcxV7eU5sfcYxLzzVgJ1LgSoebvlUXnObwqDmzy7ym
[19]   Done                    rm=sn-5uakd7d
[20]   Done                    req_id=db99eec2ba1fa3ee
[21]   Done                    ipbypass=yes
[22]   Done                    redirect_counter=2
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 172.217.130.231...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
(continues)
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0* connect to 172.217.130.231 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4006:9::7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4006:9::7: Network is unreachable
* Failed to connect to r2---sn-hgn7rn7r.googlevideo.com port 443: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to r2---sn-hgn7rn7r.googlevideo.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

- I have tried several youtube urls. Several different videos, with different formats of the URL.
- It is not a geo-blocking issue, the server is hosted in US Iowa.
- I've tried updating python to latest (3.5/6), same result.

I honestly ran out of ideas to debug this further.

EDIT: Something has sporadically changed, I can now access the direct link from the verbose output log in my local browser which I COULDN'T do before. I did not change anything since this question. Is my server's IP address being blocked? I never sent several requests to youtube to get black-listed so fast. Maybe it's not being blacklisted though, I still can't tell if it's a firewall issue. If it were a black-list issue, the verbose outputs of curl and wget would've returned an Access Denied error. So what's going on here?

Comment: Can you access the video from the server console with `wget` and `curl`? What do those commands return in verbose mode `-v`?

Comment: you said you can't wget the link in the verbose log output. is this true both on the google server and on a local machine? if it's just on the google server, then probably youtube is blacklisting those requests coming from google compute ip's?

Comment: @mebius99 I've added the verbose output of both wget and curl in the post.

Comment: @conrad Something's changed on my local machine, please check the EDIT.

Comment: @Saad, originally you intended to get the resource `https://youtu.be/tAfedFkfIiU`. Hence you should try to access exactly that link with `wget` or `curl`. I mean to try `wget -v https://youtu.be/tAfedFkfIiU` first. You will be redirected to a particular video host. If `wget` worked for you this time, you could try to get the same with the `youtube-dl` from the command line. If that worked, the problem could have been caused by an occasional connectivity issue. If `youtube-dl` failed again, the problem could be with this software or its limitations.

Comment: @mebius99 This is the output of wget -v you requested: https://hasteb.in/kohacoxu.rb It downloads the page directly. I can get the direct video host from youtube-dl's verbose output, but it can't download that video host link directly. Nor can wget. There's no problem with the actual webpage, there's a problem with the direct video host link. And it is still apparent even after weeks.

Comment: @Saad, does the yours last update ("Something has sporadically changed, I can now access the direct link") mean that the issue has gone, and youtube-dl is working flawlessly at this moment?

Comment: @mebius99 Sorry for the late reply, I couldn't figure out the issue at all, it was very sporadic and random. I'm now just using a youtube video downloading service to do the work for me. Although not ideal by any means, it gets the job done I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a "sudo" before it.
Worked for me with "sudo".

Comment: Can you explain why this makes it work? Usually the advice is to not work as root as any mistake can have big consequences.